# Redirecting stdout to swt.

Tags: java, swt, system.out

```
Display disp = Display.getCurrent();    
    disp.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try {

                PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
                System.setErr( new PrintStream(pos, true) );
                System.setOut( new PrintStream(pos, true) );

                PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream( pos );
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(pis) );

                String line = null;

                while (true){

                    line = reader.readLine(); // != null)

                    console.append(line);
                    System.out.println("moo" + line);
                    parent.layout(true,true);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to capture the contents of System.err to print them out in a debug window of my application. I can run above code but the content from System.err is not being displayed in my application, it's just being printed to console, any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with swt programming. but i remember the way to redirect stdout is to set the output stream, as you did in calling System.setErr, to a customized object that implements PrintStream. This object's `print` method will know how to update the GUI

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are echoing infinitely to `System.out`. What you probably want to do is to store the old `System.out` at the start of `run()`, and echo there rather than to the new `System.out` in your read loop.

```
PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

// ... set out and err

while(true) {
    ...
    oldOut.println("moo" + line);
}
```

**Edit:**

Also, you want to start a new thread rather than calling `asyncExec()`, which runs on the EDT and hence will cause your GUI to hang.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but after I made this change the output is still printed to console. Maybe it has something to do with the setOut being called in a seperate thread ?